# Does Django store information about who has edited and/or created a record, and if so, where?

Tags: django, authentication

Django has an [authentication and authorization scheme](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) baked in ('django.contrib.auth') as well as [modelforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) to generate forms for easy input of data into the database.

I'd like to be able to record *who* created a record, leveraging django.contrib.auth, with the explicit purpose of limiting editing of that same record to just that user and/or people with an "edit" permission.  I know that I could use the @user_passes_test decorator to restrict access to editing my record in some fashion, but I don't know what I would compare the request.user.name to in order to determine if the current user originally created that record.

How much of this do I need to roll on my own?  Do I need to capture the name author, save it to the model, and then read it - or is there something already in the framework that would do this for me?

And, if I was to attempt to save the author in a field, how would I go about doing that in such a way as to not let the user edit their own credentials?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of apps to do something similar, please check https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-audit/

About the last questions, to prevent the user not to edit its own credentials, you can mark the field with editable=False so it wont appear in the admin or ModelForms.